# Search and Hide Text Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use jQuery to look for some text and it exists I want to hide it.

So if `: Yes` exists it should be hidden.

HTML:

```
<div class="listing_detail col-md-4"><strong>Living Room:</strong><span class="hide-this-tag"> Yes</span></div>
<div class="listing_detail col-md-4"><strong>Kitchen:</strong><span class="hide-this-tag"> No</span></div>
```

Jquery:

```
 $('.listing_detail:contains("Yes")').hide('.hide-this-tag');
```

The above Jquery hides the whole div rather than just `: Yes`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ckacbuz/)

Comment: $('.listing_detail:contains("Yes")').find('.hide-this-tag').hide()
hide does not allow you to tell what hide, find element .hide-this-tag and then hide it

Comment: I literally gave you this answer in your previous question, why would you not post a comment below my answer so that I could help you further? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37165055/hide-text-after-a-tag-using-jquery/37165391#37165391

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass a selector to `.hide()`. You use it on an object:

```js
$('.listing_detail:contains("Yes")').find('.hide-this-tag').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="listing_detail col-md-4"><strong>Living Room:</strong><span class="hide-this-tag"> Yes</span></div>
<div class="listing_detail col-md-4"><strong>Kitchen:</strong><span class="hide-this-tag"> No</span></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```js
$('.hide-this-tag:contains("Yes")').hide();
OR
$('span.hide-this-tag:contains("Yes")').hide();
OR
$('div.listing_detail span.hide-this-tag:contains("Yes")').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="listing_detail col-md-4"><strong>Living Room:</strong><span class="hide-this-tag"> Yes</span></div>
<div class="listing_detail col-md-4"><strong>Kitchen:</strong><span class="hide-this-tag"> No</span></div>
```

---

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding the `.hide` at the end of the code it is selecting the selected element(`<div>`), what you need is something like this:

```
if($('.listing_detail:contains("Yes")').length > 0){
     $('.hide-this-tag').hide(); //After you checked that the "Yes" exsists, hide the tag.
}
```